# Make a part of an HTML page disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a website where I have a header section which takes up the entire viewport height. To exit this section the viewer must click a button, which then scrolls them down to the content. The design was based upon [this website](https://www.etq-amsterdam.com/).

But, they seemed to have 'cut' the top portion of the page, because you cannot scroll up there after you have left that area. How was this achieved? Is there some jQuery solution, or is it all CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I have taken a look at the page and I have come to the conclusion that the interaction is based on JavaScript. Why do I think this? Well, very simply because the intro section (`<section id="intro"></section>`) disappears from the document when the scrolling animation ends.

This is something that can be achieved using the `.remove()` function of jQuery. This function removes an element and its children from the DOM. [The documentation can be found here](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

The code that was used to pull this off, probably looks roughly like this:

```
$("#intro").remove()
```

If this interaction was done using CSS, the element would not have disappeared but instead there would have been some inline CSS added to the element (for example `<section id="intro" style="display: none;">`)

Of course this all is triggered by either a scroll or click event which would look something like this.

```
$("#intro").click(function(){
    // Code that changes element opacity as mentioned by Rahul Jain

    // You can use 'this' as the selector since you are inside a function of that same selector
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a mixture: In the `click()`-method of the button you set the div for your header to `display:none;`, like `$('#button').click(function(){$('#header').hide();});`

Comment: If you were to visit the website and inspect the HTML, you would see that the div is not set to ```display: none``` but rather disappears entirely.

Comment: And the outcome will be the same... if you set it invisible, you won't be able to scroll up again, or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, you won't be able to scroll up again but the outcome will be slightly different since hiding the element will allow you to still modify it afterwards while actually removing it won't.

Answer (score 0):

On click and mousewheel, they trigger an animation which changes the opacity of that portion from 1 to 0. And on complete of animation, they remove the element permanently using

```
$('portion-selector').remove();
```